# PHP variables are showing up with blank results

Tags: php, phpbb3

PHP newbie, so pardon the ease of this question. Why are the php variables showing up blank? Is there a hosting issue or something? Am I learning outdated info?

I using the following html method:

Nickname:


Fullname:



 Memo:

Along with php code:

```
  // File p-4-1.php
```

echo "
Nickname=$Nickname";
  echo "
Fullname=$Fullname";
  echo "
Memo=$Memo";

The result is this:

Nickname= 
Fullname= 
Memo=

My goal is to edit the phpbb forum body to include a custom form and this is how it is starting off.

Comment: can u add your code properly so that we can figure out the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question I can say this is what you are looking for

```
<?php
$nickName = "abc";
$fullName = "abc xyz";
$memo = "hello abc";

echo $nickName, $fullName, $memo;
?>
```